# How to calculate the volume under a 3d surface plot

Tags: matlab, volume

I have a 3d surface named,k for example:

```
a=8;

k(b,c)=a;

surf(k)
```

how to compute the volume and size under the surface plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is the integral (assuming k>=0). Use integral2.

```
f=@(x,y)(interp2(k,x,y))
volume = integral2(f,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)
```

Comment: i have tried the coding, but the error message appear....how to solve this problem ya?

a=8;

x=2;

y=3;

k(x,y)=a

surf(k)

f=@(x,y)(k(x,y))

volume=integral2(f,1,2,1,3)

Error message: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in @(x,y)(k(x,y))

Comment: I missed an important part. Using arrays, `f` is only defined for integer arguments. This can be fixed using interpolation. Answer updated.

Comment: hi, i called trapz twice to perform the double integration and it work ....eg:vol=trapz(trapz(k))... Thanks for ur suggestion